# how to search in spite of missing input

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a search bar with a button next to it that is connected to a database. On button click, it will get the data in the search bar, search the database and display the result. This is working so far.

What I cant figure out is how to make it search even if the data in the search bar is missing. For example, the user puts "ma" in the search bar. It will still display results like "mark", "marge", "may" and anything with a "ma". How to do this?

index.php (the search bar)

```
<SCRIPT>
        function loadSearch()
        {
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                  }
            else
                  {// code for IE6, IE5
                  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                  }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
                  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                    {
                    document.getElementById("myDivs").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
              }
            var bar = document.getElementById('sbar').value;

            xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?search="+bar,true);  
            xmlhttp.send(); 
        }
</SCRIPT>

<span class="searchbox">    
            <input type="text" class="searchbar" id = "sbar" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for site..." autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off">

            </input>
            </span>
```

search.php

```
<?php
        $getsearch = $_GET['search'];
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test1");

            // Check connection
        if (!$conn) {
            die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
                }

            $today = date("Y-m-d");
            $sql = "SELECT name, COUNT(*) as Referrals,
            SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Hired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hired,
            SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
            FROM table1
            WHERE name > '' AND name = '".$getsearch."' AND month(date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND year(date) = YEAR(NOW())
            GROUP BY name 
            ORDER BY Referrals DESC";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sql replace the `=` operator into `LIKE` with partial match symbol `%` Here I placed `%` on both side so it will search for anywhere in the string.

If you use only in left or right depends on that your result also vary depends on the search criteria.

```
$sql = "SELECT name, COUNT(*) as Referrals,
            SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Hired' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Hired,
            SUM(CASE WHEN leadstatus = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Failed
            FROM table1
            WHERE name > '' AND name LIKE '%".$getsearch."%' AND month(date) = MONTH(NOW()) AND year(date) = YEAR(NOW())
            GROUP BY name 
            ORDER BY Referrals DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your where statement in the query use LIKE instead of =

```
Where name like '%ma%'
```

Will make you search for names that contains ma inside.

```
Where name like '%$getsearch%'
```

In your specific code